# Bootstrap starter page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the end of the starter page is this:

```
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

But I think with version 2, you just include 1 JavaScript file, don't you?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This actually threw me for a loop the other day.

The bootstrap.js file in the current .zip downloadable from the Bootstrap page has all of the plugins included. You don't need to (and shouldn't) include them separately if you're using the default .js file.

Answer (score 1):

cf_PhillipSenn. The link provided by cetver in the comments is what you are looking for where you can customize what features you will be using, and then download it into a compiled file. If you know plugins you will be using from the beginning, might be the way to go.

The chunk you see on the bottom of the bootstrap page makes it easy to add / remove plugins as you need them.